# How to run a web page with cache refresh using chromium-browser and command line?

Tags: command-line, cache, browser, chrome, cookie

I can start a web page with command line like that `cromium-browser http://some-page.com`.

How can I start a web page with command line and with hard refresh cache option (equivalent of `CTRL-F5` if I tried to manually opened it with cromium)? I think there must be an argument option to do that but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you have access to the website you're trying to display? If yes, you could use  HTTP-EQUIV="refresh"

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution I have come up with so far is to clean `chromium`'s cache before opening a web page, so basically you can run these two command sequentially:

```
rm -r -f /home/poslink/.cache/chromium
cromium-browser http://some-page.com
```

As you have probably guessed `rm -r -f /home/poslink/.cache/chromium` will clean the cache by removing `/home/poslink/.cache/chromium` directory where `chromium` stores its cache, `-r` option will insure that all sub directories and files will be removed recursively, and `-f` will make sure that no error will come out if this directory does not exist.